# JAVA TFTP Clients uploads empty files when call TFTPClient sendFile() method

Tags: java, tftp

I am using a TFTPClient example to copy a file from local disk and create a file on tftp server with a new name but same contents I am sending the input stream to

```
tftpClient.sendFile(String filename, int mode, InputStream input,
                     InetAddress host, int port) method
```

the file with `fileName` is getting created on the server but with size 0.

Some more things:

- I have setup tftp server on windows8 64 bit
- able to put the file on tftp server from cmd
- I have TFTP Client enabled
- I have turned off firewall
- and I have read the lines of input stream and it actually contains data.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: So the input is zero length, or you have already consumed it before calling this method.

Comment: **Do not post code in comments.** You can see for yourself that it is completely illegible. Edit it into your question.

Comment: @EJP i have modified the question as i have checked that the inputstream is containing data but strill tftp server is creating only empty file not taking inputstream data

Comment: Your question is futile without the code. If you've read the lines of the input you have consumed it, as I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution 
the issue was due to jar file there were bugs in tftp client early release that it drops last data package the bug fixed in version 3 of commons-net.
Took the new jar issue resolved